# How to add different dependencies on different module in different profile?

Tags: maven

I have a multi modules project which manage dependencies by maven.

I have multi plugins in the sub module 'plugins'. I want to add different plugins in different scenario but there are some plugins which is need at every scenario.

the pom.xml in 'plugins' module.

```
<profiles>
   <profile>
        <id>internal</id>
        <modules>
            <module>first-plugin</module>
        </modules>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.first.groups</groupId>
                <artifactId>first-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            <dependency>
        </dependencies>
   </profile>
</profiles>
<modules>
    <module>second_module</module>
</modules>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.first.groups</groupId>
        <artifactId>second-module</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    <dependency>
</dependencies>
```

No matter I run 'mvn package' or 'mvn package -P internal', it only container the second-module as the dependencies. anyone knows the reason?

My maven version is 3.3.9

Answer (score 0):

So, if you ask the idea way to do it than it will be like this:

1. Create one parent project which is responsible for building all the projects
     e.g.

> ```
>          <modules>
>             <module>first _module</module>
>             <module>second_module</module>
>           </modules>
> ```

2. Use Dependency management to manage dependency

   ```
   <dependencyManagement/> tag
   ```
3. if there are common dependency in all the modules than put that dependency in parent and refer that project as parent project with  tag in all the modules. so, all the projects will get the common dependences
4. Only put specific dependency in specific projects
5. Beware about cyclic dependency. Create and provide dependency very carefully.

Comment: I do not think it is a good idea. It will break my project construct. I still want to use maven profile to resolve this problem.